# Visual Studio C# How to paste line after caret

Tags: c#, visual-studio, copy-paste

When I copy a line using Ctrl+C without a selection, Ctrl+V will result in the line being inserted above my selection, even if the caret is after something.

Example:

```
Foo();
Bar(); X
```

Pasting line 1 at X will result in

```
Foo();
Foo();
Bar();
```

Is there a possibility to instead achieve something more like this?

```
Foo();
Bar(); 
Foo();
```

This only happens if I both copy and paste without a selection. Selecting the entire line and copying will result in Foo being pasted after Bar, same happens when pasting into some selected text.

I am currently using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: I cannot recreate this behaviour in VS2017 Enterprise. Everything gets pasted where the caret is, as one would expect.

Comment: I added that this only happens without a selection, does this still not happen in your VS?

Comment: Ah, indeed, it does work in this way if you make no selection. I have to admit I never use ctrl-C without a selection... well, the easy way around it is to hit enter before ctrl-V of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can configure it, but you can workaround it by using 'Move Selected Lines Up' feature

1. Paste (Ctrl+V)
2. Move line up (Alt+Up Arrow)

Keyboard shortcuts might be different depending on your VS settings. You can find this feature "in Edit->Advanced->Move Selected Lines Up"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command (C# language) with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to paste a line after the current one:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineDown");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
}
```